# Добавить distinct в направление

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно добавить distinct в направление, в этой колонке не должно быть повторяющихся значений (правильный вариант ниже).

```
select distinct    decode(grouping(s.name),1,'все_направления',s.name) as направление,
count(distinct(s.name)) as cnt
from employees x
left join staff y on x.id_e=y.id_e
left join division z on z.id_d=y.id_d
left join scientific_degree l on x.id_e=l.id_e
left join scientific_direction s on s.id_direction = l.id_direction
group by rollup(z.abbreviation,s.name,l.d_start)
having count (l.id_direction) > 0 and l.d_start in (select max(sd.d_start)
from scientific_degree sd
where sd.d_start = l.d_start)
order by направление;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Как сделать чтобы выводилось по 1 подразделению? Сейчас выводит 7 раз одно и то же н-р по АПГМ* Уберите `направление` из списка вывода - тогда эти 7 записей можно схлопнуть в одну (группировкой или DISTINCT).

Comment: убрал, а как правильно distinct запихнуть?

Comment: А это зависит от требуемого результата... Скорее всего просто `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: Почему вы считаете по s.name, и групируете по s.name одновременно? Вы хотите в cnt еденицы видеть?

Comment: Т.е. другое число, отличное от 1 не может быть? Если да, то можно вместо count просто 1 писать...? И зачем тогда cnt в order by писать?

Comment: И `select distinct
decode(grouping(s.name) и так далее` добавление distinct правда не помагает? (Только тогда на первое время order by нужно убрать, при distinct нельзя порядок отличный от дистинкта делать) Вы использовали distinct ранее?

Comment: Да, я вот как раз пытался использовать distinct с decode и grouping, но постоянно выдает ошибку. Ранее в селект пробовал но не работало

Comment: Поставьте `distinct` и закомметрируйте или уберите `order by` совсем. `distinct` плохо дружит с `order by`. Если получится, то в order by можно или 1 (не помню поддерживает ли оракл по-номерам столбцов) поставить, или точно такое же значение как при верхнем (первом) select, иначе будет ошибку выдавать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас есть дубли то - у вас неправильно записано выражение в Group by. Я не знаю как у вас организована работа, и кто придумал в Group by поставить ф-цию (udp для оракла может быть так можно, но надо дополнительно изучать), но я вам советую её оттуда убрать, или хотя бы если не убрать, то привести в порядок выражение групировки. Иначе вам тут помочь не смогут. Типичный запрос на статистику по полю имеет вид

```
select group1, count(*) from table1
group by group1

select group1,group2, count(*) from table1
group by group1,group2

select group1, group2, и так далее, count(*) from table1 
group by group1, group2 и так далее`
```

если вы приведете выборку к такому виду у вас проблем не  будет. group1 и тут и там должно совпадать. Пробую привести вашу выборку к такому виду (я поначалу не знал что у вас оракл, ответ - общий предполагая что среда sql не извесна)

```
select 
decode(grouping(s.name),1,'все_направления',s.name) as направление, -- тут
count(distinct(s.name)) as cnt, -- это к-во направлений
count(distinct(x.id)) cnt2 -- а может всётаки к-во служащих, а не к-во направлений?
from employees x
left join staff y on x.id_e=y.id_e
left join division z on z.id_d=y.id_d
left join scientific_degree l on x.id_e=l.id_e
left join scientific_direction s on s.id_direction = l.id_direction
group by 
    decode(grouping(s.name),1,'все_направления',s.name) -- и тут должно совпадать    
having count (l.id_direction) > 0 and l.d_start in (select max(sd.d_start)
from scientific_degree sd
where sd.d_start = l.d_start)
order by z.abbreviation,cnt desc;
```

Данная выборка будет правильна с точки зрения программиста, но вам она вероятнее всего не подойдет.

У меня вопрос, 1)зачем вам к-во подразделений если вы групируете по подразделению. 2)где ваше z в select?

Я не пойду что вы хотите считать, потому что нельзя групировать по тому что считашь, иначе тупо будут получаться еденицы - и это нормально. Если надо получить число отличное от ноль и один (ноль получится только если s.name попадется null такие могут быть, могут не быть в вашей БД) - то нужно групировать по другим полям, которые имеют концептуальное значение группа. Если у вас всегда еденица - то можно так и записать (схематически) `select group1, 1 as cnt from table1 group by group1`. Я вижу выборку примерно так (схематически)

```
select [подразделение],[направление], count (*) from ваша_таблица
/*Ваши условия 1*/
group by  [подразделение],[направление]
/*Ваши условия 2  having  и т п*/
order by 1,2
```

Возможно это будет так

```
select z.abbreviation, s.name dir, count(distinct(x.id)) cnt 
from employees x
left join staff y on x.id_e=y.id_e
left join division z on z.id_d=y.id_d
left join scientific_degree l on x.id_e=l.id_e
left join scientific_direction s on s.id_direction = l.id_direction
group by 
   z.abbreviation, s.name    
-- Далее хвост, не могу сказать будет ли этот хвост дружить с головой, отдельно сработает но прийдется добавлять условия что б отсечь лишнее
having count (l.id_direction) > 0 and l.d_start in (select max(sd.d_start)
from scientific_degree sd
where sd.d_start = l.d_start)
order by z.abbreviation,cnt desc;
```

---

Теперь про distinct. Обычно distinct хорошо работает, но есть ограничение. order by можно делать только по полям которые при select distinct, в некоторых версиях sql можно по "прямым выражениям" от данных полей. Т.е

```
select distinct    decode(grouping(s.name),1,'все_направления',s.name) as направление,
count(distinct(s.name)) as cnt
from employees x
left join staff y on x.id_e=y.id_e
left join division z on z.id_d=y.id_d
left join scientific_degree l on x.id_e=l.id_e
left join scientific_direction s on s.id_direction = l.id_direction
group by rollup(z.abbreviation,s.name,l.d_start)
having count (l.id_direction) > 0 and l.d_start in (select max(sd.d_start)
from scientific_degree sd
where sd.d_start = l.d_start)
/*вариант 1*/ order by направление -- если можно в вашем sql по алиасу 
/*вариант 2*/ order by 1 -- если можно в sql по номеру поля
/*вариант 3*/ order by decode(grouping(s.name),1,'все_направления',s.name) -- если можно в вашем sql по выражению
```

К сожалению разные версии sql по разному разрешают запись в `order by`, поэтому попробуйте по одному из трех вариантов.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ, пробую прогнать по 2-му способу. Пишет ошибку в первой строке "ORA-00904: "X"."ID": недопустимый идентификатор". ПО поводу вопроса - подразделения в выводе вообще не нужны. Т.е по идее в окне вывода должны быть 2 колонки - направления и cnt.

Comment: Вы бы чирканули в вопросе что у вас Оракл, или соответствующую метку добавили. Я ещё подумал что какие-то странные записи присутствуют в вашем запросе - вам бы правильнее ответили, я вам написал как для mssql. Один из ответов вам дали тоже для mssql. cube/rollup - не знаю что это.

Comment: Счёт статистики - называется агрегированый запрос. Все поля должны быть либо сгрупированы (находится в `group by` и могут быть в select могут не быть), либо агрегироваными, т.е. быть внутри агрегатных функций (count sum min max и другие). Например если у вас есть три поля a b c, то можно делать или так `select a, b, count(c) from table1 group by a,b` или так `select a, count(c) from table1 group by a`. Означает что колонка без которой group by не работает - она находится при select прямо или косвенно (через функцию) задействована. Если её убрать, то можно и с `group by` убрать.

Comment: Ещё подсказка, если вам нужно лишь наличие, то можно записать вот так `select a, 1 as cnt from table1 group by a`. Тогда под любой группой будет еденица. Вариант 2 `select distinct a, 1 as cnt from table1` (думаю что оба запроса дадут одинаковый результат, но первым вариантом свободы больше)

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT DISTINCT <текст запроса>`

Уберёт повторяющиеся по всем полям записи;

Comment: пробовал в селект пихнуть, не робит

Answer (score 3):

Для удаления дубликатов по конкретным атрибутам можете попробовать использовать оконную функцию row_number(), которая нумерует строки с повторяющимися указанными атрибутами.

Пример использования для удаления дубликатов по повторяющимся полям Attr1, Attr2 из таблицы #tmp (ID, Attr1, Attr2):

```
DELETE #tmp
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT A.ID
    from (
        SELECT ID, Attr1, Attr2, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (   
                PARTITION BY Attr1, Attr2
                ORDER BY ID
            ) as uniqchk
        FROM #tmp
        ) as A
WHERE A.uniqchk <> 1

)
```

В данном случае, вместо таблицы #tmp будет ваш запрос в качестве подзапроса. Но тогда надо немного обернуть условие из удаления на фильтрацию:

```
    SELECT ID, Attr1, Attr2
    from (
        SELECT ID, Attr1, Attr2, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (   
                PARTITION BY Attr1, Attr2
                ORDER BY ID
            ) as uniqchk
        FROM #tmp
        ) WHERE uniqchk = 1
```

Примерно как-то так. Извините, но повозиться с синтаксисом придется вам, либо кому-то поправить мой ответ, потому что я уже давно не практиковался с sql. Я стремлюсь помочь вам подсказав нестандартный подход к логике решения удаления дубликатов.

Comment: Так не работает. Столбец с именем **smth** существовать не будет.

Comment: ну в подзапрос можно тогда сунуть. Смысл в том, что существует row_number(), если уже ничего не помогает)

Comment: отредактировал ответ, добавил пример использования. Смысл в том, что функция row_number партицирует по указанным полям, а внутри каждой партиции нумерует записи. Таким образом, записи, в которых совпадает Attr1, Attr2, будут пронумерованы, а значит записи с номером 2 и больше - дубликаты и их можно удалить (Что мы и делаем в самом корне запроса).

Comment: Проще и крайне грубо говоря, если понимаете как работает group by, эта функция нумерует элементы внутри одной группы

Answer (score 1):

```
select P1,P2,P3,P4 
   from Table1
 where (P1,P2) in (select P1,P2 
                            from Table1
```

Comment: Извините, а что делает этото запрос, не подскажете?  На первый взгляд он абсолютно безсмысленный.